# React Number Format Styling

Tags: css, reactjs

Attempting to style a `react-number-format` component by adding a `className` does not work.  How do I style this component?

```
<NumberFormat
    thousandSeparator={true}
    prefix={'$'}
    decimalScale={2}
    fixedDecimalScale={true}
    id={props.id}
    name={props.id}
    value={props.value}
    autoFocus={props.autofocus}
    onChange={props.changehandler}    
    className="newclass"
/>
```

CSS

```
.currency{ background-color: green}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, I did not have the react engine running, so refreshing the page resulted in no changes.  Early Morning rookie mistake.

Answer (score 0):

From there [documentation](https://github.com/s-yadav/react-number-format) page, use the ['custom input'](https://github.com/s-yadav/react-number-format#custom-inputs) prop to pass your own component, which you can style just the way you like it:

> You can easily extend your custom input with number format. But custom input should have all input props.

---

```js
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
<NumberFormat customInput={TextField} format="#### #### #### ####"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <NumberFormat
        thousandSeparator={true}
        prefix={'$'}
        decimalScale={2}
        fixedDecimalScale={true}
        id={props.id}
        name={props.id}
        value={props.value}
        autoFocus={props.autofocus}
        onChange={props.changehandler}    
        className="currency

"
/>
```

CSS

.`currency{ background-color: green}`